# Cannot access to laravel.dev:8000 "ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, virtualbox, homestead

After installing vagrant successfully creating a new VM in Virtual-box, also created a new project named Laravel and the key to enter by ssh, got both Laravel in `/Code/Laravel`, and on my machine `C:\Users\Micaelsf\Project\PHP\Laravel`.

Seems ok, but the problem is, I cannot access the `laravel.dev:8000 url`.

After troubleshooting hosts file and `homestead.yaml` file:

**Hosts file: (in the end of the file)**

```
laravel.dev 192.168.10.10
```

**homestead.yaml file:**

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"

..

authorize: `C:\Users\Micaelsf\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`

keys:

    - C:\Users\Micaelsf\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:

    - map: C:\Users\Micaelsf\Project\PHP

      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:

    - map: laravel.dev

      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Seems ok, I can access `192.168.10.10:8000` but not `laravel.dev:8000`

I pinged `laravel.dev` and the ping was successfully, but the ip shown was `127.0.53.53`, which is a loopback address, obviously need to be successful.

After all this, still not understand what is failing to cannot access the link.

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much in advance.

PS: I'am using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The line in your hosts file is reversed. The IP address comes first, and is followed by a (space delimited) list of hostnames that should resolve to that IP address.

So, update your hosts file to:

```
192.168.10.10 laravel.dev
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: After fixing hosts file, still can´t connect to laravel.dev:8000, i've heard something about symlinks, between my hard disk and VM files, but can't found the solution.